# positioning nested divs relative to each other

Tags: html, css

This is the html for a chart. I want the second (middle) div to start where the first (top) div ends (i.e. at the right end of its 75px width), so in the styles below, I set the `margin-left` for the middle div to be 75px. Continuing this pattern, I want the third (bottom) div to start where the middle div ends. Since the width of the top and middle divs are 120px, I set the `margin-left:` for the bottom div to `120px`. As you can see from [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/89tj2/1/), the three divs all start from the left edge instead of indenting the desired number of pixels.

What's the proper way to achieve this effect that I can't get my clumsy way?  (note, the divs should remain on separate lines, not be combined into one line)

HTML

```
 <div class="another_chart">Blah blah graph
      <div class="another_blue" style="width: 75px;">25</div>
      <div class="another_pink" style="width: 45px;">15</div>
      <div class="another_yellow" style="width: 60px;">20</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.another_chart div {
    text-align:right;
    padding:3px;
    margin:1px;
    color:#000;
    width:600px
}

.another_blue {
    font:15px sans-serif;
    background-color:#4682b4;
    text-align:right;
    padding:3px;
    margin:1px;
    color:#fff;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px
}

.another_pink {
    font:15px sans-serif;
    background-color:#f5c5f2;
    text-align:right;
    padding:3px;
    margin-left:75px;//the middle div should start 75px from the left color  
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px
}

.another_yellow {
    font:15px sans-serif;
    background-color:#ebfa02;
    text-align:right;
    padding:3px;
    margin-left:120px;//the bottom div should start 120px from the left
    color
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float to the left and apply a top margin.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/89tj2/10/)

CSS

```
.another_chart div {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="another_chart">
    <div class="another_blue" style="width: 75px;">25</div>
    <div class="another_pink" style="width: 45px; margin-top: 2em;">15</div>
    <div class="another_yellow" style="width: 60px;  margin-top: 4em;">20</div>
</div>
```

You can also remove some redundant CSS styles:

[Cleaner fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/89tj2/11/)

```
.another_chart div {
    text-align: right;
    font: 15px sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
    color: #000;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
}
.another_blue {
    background-color: steelblue;
}
.another_pink {
    background-color: #f5c5f2;
}
.another_yellow {
    background-color: #ebfa02;
}
```

Comment: I take my hat off to you.